# Resetting Index When Reading Unique Keys with SharedPreferences"

Tags: flutter, algorithm

I have unique keys in the shared preference file, and I need to read them one by one and store them in an array of users that I create. The problem is that when I use this algorithm, the index is reset each time, so I can't get 2 records. Where should I reset the index?Or This is not a good appoach?Thank in advance

```
 List<User> users = [];
  late int loopVal=0;
  int index = 0;

  String nameValue = "";
  String emailValue = "";
  String scorValue = "";

  Future<void> _getUsersData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> keys = prefs.getKeys().toList();

    do {


      for (String key in keys) {
        Object? userData = prefs.get(key);
        // Kullanıcı adını ayarlayın
        if (index == 0) {
          nameValue = userData.toString();
          index++;
        } else if (index == 1) {
          scorValue = userData.toString();
          index++;
        } else if (index == 2) {
          emailValue = userData.toString();
          index++;
        } else {
          user=User(//add list
          index = 0;
          loopVal++;
          break; // Döngüyü sonlandırın
        }

        // Do something at least once
      }
    } while (loopVal <= keys.length);
  }
```

this  Share pref file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_name">aaa</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_email">digrev@gmail.com</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_score">4</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_score">0</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_name">uuu</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_password">123</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_email">digrev@gmail.com</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_password">123</string>
</map>
```